# Weiszfeld's Algorithm In Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I am taking a course completely out of my major trying to learn some new stuff. I have never coded anything before, and I find out now that most of the students have had previous courses in Matab.

I am tasked with creating a program that will find an optimal plant location using Weiszfeld's Algorithm. I  have come up with the code below so far:

```
A= [10,2];
B= [6,10];
C= [8,6];
D= [12,5];

x= 6;
y= 5;
z= 2;
w= 4;

x_value = 0;
y_value = 0;

while 
    score =
    while score > 0.001
        x_value =
        y_value =
    end
end
```

I do not know how to enter the summation for these things, or to properly execute. The `A`, `B` ,`C` ,`D` are previous locations and the `x` ,`y` ,`z` ,`w` are `cost*frequency=W` for each respective piece.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to ask a much more specific question. No one is going to implement an algorithm for you. StackOverflow is not a substitute for spending a bit of time to learn the language. Before you proceed further, I suggest that you stop, and go through a tutorial or two. The MathWorks lists [numerous tutorials](http://mathworks.com/academia/student_center/tutorials/launchpad.html) on their site‌​. See also the [User Guide](http://mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/getstart.pdf) (PDF), which has a nice quick start section.

Comment: There are also [numerous](http://mathworks.com/videos/search.html) [videos](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/) available if you prefer those - here's a [Getting Started video](http://mathworks.com/videos/getting-started-with-matlab-68985.html).